# NOT IN subquery with hiveql retuning NullPointerException null

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to run a query in hive involving inlining 2 arrays in the same table and effectively taking the difference using NOT IN operator

```
select c1 from t1 
lateral view inline(m1) m1
where m1.key = 'x'
AND t1.c1 NOT IN
(
select c1 from t1
lateral view inline(m2) m2
where m2.key = 'y'
);
```

The above query returns

```
FAILED: NullPointerException null
```

Answer (score 1):

First filter out all c1 having value 'y'

```
With temp as
(select distinct c1 from t1
lateral view inline(m2) m2
where m2.key = 'y') 

select c1 from t1 
lateral view inline(m1) m1
where m1.key = 'x')
and c1 not in (select c1 from temp)
```

Comment: This works. However, why does it explicitly need a temp table? Something to do with inline operation?